# How to train Tortoise-TTS on italian language?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, text-to-speech

I want to adapt Tortoise-TTS for Italian.
https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts

I asked the author on Github, he replied: you need to train Tortoise on audio chunks in Italian (<60 bits), then transcribe them and train Tortoise on audio samples and transcriptions.
https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/issues/5

I have audio samples and transcripts.
What to do next? In what folder should they be placed and how to start the train?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.